# Changing dictionary keys with a function

Tags: python

Suppose a dictionary like

```
d1 = {
    'a b':1,
    'c-d':2,
    'Ef':3
}
```

I want to run a function that renames all the keys according to some rules, for example lowercasing and changing spaces and - to _. So as to get the result:

```
d2 = {
    'a_b':1,
    'c_d':2,
    'ef':3
}
```

The difference between this question and the other similar questions on this site about renaming dictionary keys, is that here we don't know the columns beforehand. So we want to run a renaming function on all the keys (to normalize them or something like that).

Comment: just loop through each key/value into a new dict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare such a function, then use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (search for "dict comprehensions") to loop over the [dict items](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and call that transformer.

```
def transform_key(key):
    return key.lower().replace(" ", "_").replace("-", "_")

d1 = {
    'a b':1,
    'c-d':2,
    'Ef':3
}

d2 = {transform_key(key): value for (key, value) in d1.items()}
print(d2)
```

outputs

```
{'a_b': 1, 'c_d': 2, 'ef': 3}
```